# How the slider can move to a certain size?

Tags: javascript, html, css

My next button on slider must move slider to next slides

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="styles/style.css">
  <title>Document</title>
</head>

<body>
  <div class="container">
    <div class="slider">
      <div class="slides-container">
        <div class="slides slide1"></div>
        <div class="slides slide2"></div>
        <div class="slides slide3"></div>
        <div class="slides slide4"></div>
      </div>
      <button class="slider-btn next-btn">next</button>
      <button class="slider-btn pre-btn">pre</button>
    </div>
  </div>
  <script src="scripts/script.js"></script>
</body>

</html>
```

```
* {
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  text-decoration: none;
  list-style-type: none;
  font-family: roboto;
}
.container {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
  width: 100vw;
  min-height: 100vh;
  background-color: #fce9fa;
}
.slider {
  padding: 16% 40%;
  min-width: 800px;
  min-height: 300px;
  /* border: 1px solid red; */
  position: relative;
}
.slides-container {
  position: absolute;
  left: 0;
  top: 0;
  width: 80vw;
  height: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  min-width: 800px;
  min-height: 300px;
  border-radius: 25px;
  box-shadow: 10px 10px 20px -15px black, inset 0px 0px 280px 2px rgb(0, 0, 0);
  background-color: rgb(255, 255, 255);
  overflow: hidden;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: flex-start;
  align-items: center;
}
.slide1 {
  min-width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  background-image: url(../resource/images/slider/1.jpg);
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  background-size: 100%;
  background-position: 0px -80px;
  transition: all 0.2s ease-in;
}
.slide2 {
  min-width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  background-image: url(../resource/images/slider/2.jpg);
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  background-size: 100%;
  background-position: 0px -80px;
  transition: all 0.2s ease-in;
}
.slide3 {
  min-width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  background-image: url(../resource/images/slider/3.jpg);
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  background-size: 100%;
  background-position: 0px -80px;
  transition: all 0.2s ease-in;
}
.slide4 {
  min-width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  background-image: url(../resource/images/slider/4.jpg);
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  background-size: 100%;
  background-position: 0px -80px;
  transition: all 0.2s ease-in;
}
.slider-btn {
  position: absolute;
  top: 92%;
  width: 50px;
  padding: 5px;
  text-transform: uppercase;
  border: none;
  border-radius: 5px;
  background-color: black;
  color: white;
  font-weight: bold;
  cursor: pointer;
}
.slider-btn:hover {
  box-shadow: inset 0px 0px 0px 1px pink;
}
.next-btn {
  right: 20px;
}
.pre-btn {
  left: 20px;
}
```

I wrote this code, and I tried to be dynamic

- so I tried to give all slides with `querySelectorAll` as an array
- then I tried to move slides depend on every slide width
- and move the slides to the length of the array

but my slider move one more than Array length

```
// get elements
var slider = document.querySelector(".slider");
var sliderContainer = document.querySelector(".slides-container");
var nextBtn = document.querySelector(".next-btn");
var preBtn = document.querySelector(".pre-btn");
var eachSlide = document.querySelectorAll(".slides");
var x = 0;
// commands
console.log(slider);
console.log(sliderContainer);
console.log(eachSlide);

nextBtn = nextBtn.addEventListener("click", nextSlide);
function nextSlide() {
  if (x < eachSlide[0].clientWidth * eachSlide.length) {
    console.log(x);
    x += eachSlide[0].clientWidth;
    console.log(x);
    eachSlide.forEach((element) => {
      element.style.transform = `translateX(${-x}px)`;
      element.style.transition = "all 1.5s ease-out";
    });
  } else if (x == eachSlide[0].clientWidth * eachSlide.length) {
    x = 0;
    eachSlide.forEach((element) => {
      element.style.transform = `translateX(${-x}px)`;
    });
  }
}
```

Comment: Hi Majid, take a look at: https://www.w3schools.com/howto/howto_js_slideshow.asp

Comment: i saw it but its differenet than my project